How to add custom application for default starter in phprunner
I want to add custom application for default starter in phprunner pro v10.
I mean, at the homepage of phprunner which we are going to start our project, I need to add my own custom admin theme as starter for rapid application development.
new project
I wonder if this is even possible or not, if yes, I would really appreciate if you tell me how to do this...
Thanks.

Adding a custom application as a default starter in PHPRunner Pro v10 is indeed possible. You can achieve this by creating a template that includes your custom admin theme.

Prepare your custom admin theme and save the project as a template
Set the template as default

For Windows: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHPRunner10\templates
For macOS, it will be within the PHPRunner application package.

Modify the configuration file

Open templates\default and look for a configuration file (e.g., config.xml or similar).
